# Error occurred while invoking procedure

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I am using IBM MobileFirst 7.0. I am getting following error message when I invoke a procedure.

> [6/6/16 15:13:18:516 IST] 000000e6 DataAccessSer E  logError FWLSE0099E: An error occurred while invoking procedure  [project PNotifications]AllInOneAdapter/HttpRequestFWLSE0100E:  parameters: [project PNotifications]
>   Http request failed: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
>   FWLSE0101E: Caused by:  [project PNotifications]java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed outjava.lang.RuntimeException: Http request failed: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

**Below is log of adapter :**

[6/6/16 15:13:18:519 IST] 000000e6 JavaScriptInt I com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptIntegrationLibraryImplementation 
info

```
{
   "errors": [
      "Runtime: Http request failed: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out"
   ],
   "info": [
   ],
   "isSuccessful": false,
   "warnings": [ ]
} [project PNotifications]
```

I am facing this issue intermittently on the QA server which is at client-side. The app works perfectly at times, before this issue occurs randomly. I never faced this issue in the development environment.

I also tried increasing the connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds value to 90000 but the issue still persists. As this issue occurs randomly we haven't been able to find the cause for it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to check your network because that is where the problem is... find me logs, like a wireshark log and see what is happening on the network.

Comment: ok Idan, I'll do that

Comment: I suspect that a firewall or otherwise a network appliance is interfering. Can you check with your IT department?

Comment: We are deploying the app at client-side and we are still coordinating with their IT team. I'll let you know when we get the logs.

Comment: any updates with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The above mentioned problem was caused due to firewall settings at client-side which prevented connection at times.